# How to import more than 1 file at once into the svn repository

Tags: unix, svn

As far as I know the `import` command needs the destination file name everytime when we try to import the files.

```
svn import file1.txt https:\\server\path\file1.txt
```

My question is is there a way similar to Linux where we can copy/import multiple files at once,something like

```
svn import *.* https:\\server\path\
```

Is this possible? I don't want to use a looping process to achieve this.

Comment: write a loop of the file directory and path in each file name perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

The description of the command should give you a clue: ["svn import — Commit an unversioned file or tree into the repository"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html).

Give `svn import` a directory instead of a single file, and all files inside will be imported, recursively by default. `svn:ignore` and related properties and settings apply, for filtering out files you don't want added.

Comment: "svn help import" says "-F [--file] ARG : read log message from file ARG", not importing a list of files

Comment: Right you are. It looks like version 1.7 may have been less clear but now 5 years later I have no idea if what I wrote was ever correct or ever had a similar option. I can't find anything similar now. Removing.